# This site doesn't work on my iPad. Suggestion

Tags: feature-request

Maybe it's me. My iPad is a bit old. But, if *entire* replies were included in emails, then I wouldn't have to fire up my desktop computer to read them. (It's my always handy iPad that I use for email.)

Comment: Welcome to [Meta](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Could you [edit] and explain more clearly what doesn't work? Also, please note that [Stack Exchange only guarantees the latest 2 versions of popular browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/241919).

Comment: You can find the list of supported browsers here: https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/ If you have an old ipad and your browser version is not there, you might have issues accessing the site.

Comment: Needs more details - please advise browser version.

Comment: "*if entire replies were included in emails*" — include a screen shot of truncated mail so that we know what the problem looks like.

Answer (score 3):

Supported browsers are shown below.
what are you using.
Please add this to your question and then flag us for a reopen.

[image]

**Browser support:**
Stacks supports the last two stable versions of each major browser. If your browser doesn’t appear in this list, it still may work, but with a degraded experience. Also, we don’t test nightly or canary builds either.

**Desktop browsers**

Chrome 110

Chrome 109

Edge 110

Edge 109

Firefox 110

Firefox 109

Opera 95

Opera 94

Safari 16.3

Safari 16.2

**Mobile browsers**

Chrome for Android 110

Safari on iOS 16.3

Safari on iOS 16.2

Comment: It's me, I guess. I'm running OS 13.3.1 on my iPad. If you've ever hit the "Update" button and experienced the wonderful Apple invention called "boot loop," you're not likely to EVER do it again. None of the buttons work in the Cookies notice, on my iPad. I can't close it and it takes up 1/4 of the screen. As a result, I can't access the window to reply or add comments. It would be useful for old Luddites like myself if entire replies were included in the emails I get. Then I would know if I want to fire up my ancient desktop computer to accept an answer or to ask for more help, etc.